# Simple .htaccess rewrite not working on GoDaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My company is stuck with GoDaddy for now, and my .htaccess rewrite isn't working. This works fine on my localhost.

The intent is to have **example.com/about** actually get **example.com/about.php**, with the URL still just showing **example.com/about**.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

I have read all the other posts about inconsistent .htaccess behavior with GoDaddy servers. I did have them confirm that mod_rewrite is enabled, and my PHP is 5.4.19. Hopefully someone has been through this already or can shed some light...

Comment: I think the problem is that not much works on GoDaddy...

Comment: I agree they are awful and have plans to dump them. Unfortunately now is not the time to migrate my whole company's email and web hosting. I just want to get this URL rewrite working for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You should simplify your rule. Go Daddy is annoying but this should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still getting a 500 Internal Server Error, however :(

Comment: Try removing this `+FollowSymlinks`

Comment: Are you getting a 500 error? Do you have access to your logs? Try removing the whole Options line just to see what message you still get.

Comment: Before it was just a 500 error. Removing the options line now yields a "Not Found" error, with an additional 500 error.

Comment: I do really hate GD. anyway, try the update and see if that helps. otherwise see if you can get your logs.

Answer (score 3):

This has come up quite a few times - GoDaddy is synonymous with problems such as these. I recommend the following:

First, place this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

# Remove php extension from the request by means of a redirect.
# This should really be for php files that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L,NC]
```

Then try **one** of the following after the above:

```
# 1. Map the request to a PHP file, if one exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

```
# 2. Map the request to a PHP file, if one exists (alternative method)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

```
# 3. Map the request to a PHP file, provided the request is not
#    a file or a directory. The PHP file in question does not need
#    to exist on the file system.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

The issue at hand may be in relation to the `Options` directive. From past experience, it generally comes from using `Includes` in this directive - I understand that GD doesn't allow these. However, you are not using them, so try any of the following combinations to see if the 500 error doesn't appear.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
```

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

```
Options -Multiviews
```

GD turns off `Indexing` by default, and so it is not necessary to use that in the `Options` directive.

*Side note:* You may already know this, but don't use `php_value` and `php_flag` in `.htaccess` files on GD hosting. Instead, you would need to create a `php5.ini` file with the values and flags set in there.

**Update:** I have remove `RewriteBase` (as it has been known to cause issues for some users) and made the redirects/rewrites relative to the root of the domain.

Comment: Mike, thank you for the very thorough response. I have tried all combinations of the above code + options, however the 500 error is all I'm getting. I am definitely blaming this one on GoDaddy. If their tech support can't get this resolved, I will be pushing my company to leave them sooner rather than later. We're spending $3-4k/yr for hosted exchange with a bunch of users and many domains, and this is the kind of service they give us :(

Comment: I've been searching for a solution to this for a while now, this is the first that has worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your server must be Linux for .htaccess to work. On GoDaddy servers it will only work on Linux hosting and not Windows hosting. For Windows hosting, you have to configure web.cong to enable rewrite rules.

Comment: What's web.cong?

Comment: Please elaborate. I am on Linux Hosting, and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this one out. Thanks again to everyone who took the time to help. There was another .htaccess file in the root directory of my hosting account that was causing the 500 error, which I removed. I then got to a 400 error, which I was able to resolve using RewriteBase. Here is the working .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /this_sites_subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^/?$ /1 [L]

Options -MultiViews                

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php
```

Comment: You left out very important details because if you are using a sub directory that changes the rules.  With your example the assumption was it was located in the root.  Make sure to provide your exact issue when askin questions and not `general` examples.

Comment: Point well taken; I'll make an effort to provide more detail next time. The URLs in my example are accurate in showing the root level of this particular site, where my files in fact are. I had no idea that a .htaccess file elsewhere on my hosting account, outside the folder that's linked to the root of this domain, would affect this site. That's the main thing I learned here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
This also helped me after a week of having headaches with GD support

Here is revices change that I made in order to have my Subdreamer (yes I know, ughhh) sites still have friendly URLs working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ /1 [L]

Options -MultiViews                

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Good luck to the rest

Answer (score 0):

As the most sites are in .php or .html

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In the GoDaddy [help page](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-use-mod-rewrite-899) on this topic, it says that

> The .htaccess file containing the rewrite rules must be in the same directory as the target files.

So, try putting a separate .htaccess file in each directory that you rewrite the urls.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Check GoDaddy server is using IIS or apache ?

- Goto plesk panel
- Click Websites and Domains from left menu
- Find IIS Settings

[IIS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRJsk.png)

Step 2 : If server is using IIS, need to use Web.config file instead of .htaccess file

Sample Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Rewrite to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/indus-admin/index.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```